# What are the Default, System and Microsoft LogLevels in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The default project template has the following logging configuration in `appSettings.json`:

```
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": true,
  "LogLevel": 
    "Default": "Debug",
    "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
}
```

What are `Default`, `System` and `Microsoft` for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the `System` and `Microsoft` namespace assemblies have a logging level that is honored. Consider an **MVC 6** application, imagine in your `project.json` that you have a dependency of `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final"` - this assembly is prefixed with "Microsoft". Internally its logging will be output with the level specified in your config.

Likewise, in your application `"Default"` is relevant to your application. Consider the following:

```
void FooBar(ILogger logger)
{
    logger.LogCritical("LoglLevel.Critical");
    logger.LogDebug("LoglLevel.Debug");
    logger.LogError("LoglLevel.Errror");
    logger.LogInformation("LoglLevel.Information");
    logger.LogTrace("LoglLevel.Trace"); // This message would not be written
    logger.LogWarning("LoglLevel.Warning");
}

// This is the severity
public enum LogLevel
{
    Trace,
    Debug,
    Information,
    Warning,
    Error,
    Critical,
    None
}
```

So if you set `"Microsoft": "Critical"` and internally MVC encounters and logs an exception via the `logger.LogError` method, it will not be written in the output of the log.

Comment: Are these based on namespace or assembly name? Also, can we add our own names to the list?

Comment: Also, it seems that you can use a namespace and even a type name.